# Finest grain at which a CPU usage can be logged / recorded

Tags: cpu-usage

There is something fractal to CPU loads. Depending on the time resolution at which you look at the output of typical "procstat" or "top" programs, the slope will look more or less detailed.

Apart from "load" programs, that take the "average" CPU usage over 1, 5, 15 minutes, many tools give CPU usage with a *second* accuracy.

When the sampling rate becomes higher than the free / malloc frequencies of a program, spikes start to become visible on a graph where the CPU usage seemed smooth.

The question is : what is the highest possible sampling rate possible / available, to display a CPU usage ?

Like in quantic systems, measuring probably changes the state of the entity that is measured (if the sampling tool runs on the CPU that is sampled). Are there any systems where CPU usage is monitored, very accurately, from another, external CPU, in a way that the measurements have no effect of the load of the monitored CPU ?